# haskell syntax with foldr and 'where'

Tags: haskell, syntax

`foldr (+) 0 [1,2]`  returns `3`

How could I write it using `'where'`?

`foldr f 0 [1,2] where f = (+)` returns `"parse error on input 'where'"`

Edit:
actually I'm trying to make cartesian product as in the example

```
cprod = foldr f [[ ]]
where f xs yss = foldr g [ ] xs
where g x zss = foldr h zss yss
where h ys uss = (x : ys) : uss
```

but, this again gives parse error on input `where`, when I'm trying to load the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`... where ...` is not an expression. `where` is associated with bindings, not expressions.

You could use `let`: `let f = (+) in foldr f 0 [1,2]`, or you could use it with some binding: `x = foldr f 0 [1,2] where f = (+)`.

---

The following is a syntactically valid version of your edited code (it's still broken, but that's not a syntactic issue anymore :-) ). You only want to use one `where` per binding, and you want the `where` to be more indented than the body of the function.

```
cprod = foldr f [[ ]]
  where
    f xs yss = foldr g [ ] xs
    g x zss = foldr h zss yss
    h ys uss = (x : ys) : uss
```

---

Looking again, I see that I misunderstood your code -- you had three `where`s because you wanted each one to apply to the previous functions. In that case you have to indent the `where`s the way I said, e.g.

```
cprod = foldr f [[ ]]
  where f xs yss = foldr g [ ] xs
          where g x zss = foldr h zss yss
                  where h ys uss = (x : ys) : uss
```

If you insist on using `where` like this and don't like deeply indented code, you can use explicit `{}`/`;` rather than layout. An extreme case would be

```
{
cprod = foldr f [[ ]]
where { f xs yss = foldr g [ ] xs
where { g x zss = foldr h zss yss
where { h ys uss = (x : ys) : uss } } }
}
```

But this isn't usually considered good style.

Comment: I am not an expert in Haskell, but should be with '3' wheres ? similar to what dave4420 did?

Answer (score 3):

In response to your edit, your code should be

```
cprod = foldr f [[ ]]
  where f xs yss = foldr g [ ] xs
          where g x zss = foldr h zss yss
                  where h ys uss = (x : ys) : uss
```

The important things are:

- `where` is attached to an equation, not to an expression
- the `where` must be indented relative to the equation it's attached to (so the first `where` is more indented than `cprod`, the second `where` is more indented than `f`, etc)
- shachaf's answer is correct syntactically; but your example code has `h` using the `x` defined in `g`, and `g` using the `yss` defined in `f`, which is why in this case we do need an additional `where` for each extra function

Comment: I've been sitting for an hour, but still can't understand how does this code make cartesian product of all lists of the list, could you give some hint?

Comment: @Herokiller Best to ask a new top level question where everybody can see it.

Comment: @Herokiller But first you might want to write type signatures for `cprod`, `f`, `g` and `h`; then try to work out what `h` does before trying to work out what `g` does, etc.